# how can I import a database by running just one command?

Tags: postgresql, pg-restore

I try to learn how to import [a database](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/dvdrental.zip) into PostgreSQL.

My attempt failed, where I use `pg_restore -C ... -d ...` to combine creation of a new database and importing from the file to the new database in one command:

```
$ sudo -u postgres pg_restore -C -d postgres dvdrental.tar 
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error while PROCESSING TOC:
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 2194; 1262 17355 DATABASE pagila postgres
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  invalid locale name: "English_United States.1252"
    Command was: CREATE DATABASE pagila WITH TEMPLATE = template0 ENCODING = 'UTF8' LC_COLLATE = 'English_United States.1252' LC_CTYPE = 'English_United States.1252';            
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  database "pagila" does not exist
    Command was: ALTER DATABASE pagila OWNER TO postgres;        
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not reconnect to database: FATAL:  database "pagila" does not exist
```

My questions are:

- I was wondering why my first attempt failed?
- Is there a way by running just one command?

The document says:

> -C
>   --create
>
> Create the database before restoring into it. If  --clean  is also specified, drop and recreate the target database before
>   connecting to it.

and even provide an example:

> Assume we have dumped a database called  mydb  into a custom-format
>   dump file:
>
> ```
> $ pg_dump -Fc mydb > db.dump
> ```
>
> To drop the database and recreate it from the dump:
>
> ```
> $ dropdb mydb
> $ pg_restore -C -d postgres db.dump
> ```
>
> The database named in the  -d  switch can be any database existing in
>   the cluster; pg_restore only uses it to issue the  CREATE DATABASE 
>   command for  mydb . With  -C , data is always restored into the
>   database name that appears in the dump file.

Thanks.

---

**Update:**

Thanks again. I found the binary file `toc.dat` in the dump contains the

```
CREATE DATABASE pagila WITH TEMPLATE = template0 ENCODING = 'UTF8' LC_COLLATE = 'English_United States.1252' LC_CTYPE = 'English_United States.1252';`
```

Is it possible modify it to make `sudo -u postgres pg_restore -C -d postgres dvdrental.tar` work?

---

Note that I have a working soluton:

Separate  creation of a new database in `psql` and  importing from the file to the new database:

```
template1=# CREATE DATABASE dvdrental;
CREATE DATABASE

$ sudo -u postgres pg_restore -d dvdrental dvdrental.tar
$
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your import failed because the operating system where you are trying to import the dump does not know the locale `English_United States.1252`. Either the operating system is not Windows, or the Windows doesn't have that locale installed.

`pg_restore -C` tries to create the database in the same way as it was on the original system, which is not possible. Explicitly creating the database works because it uses a locale that exists.

There is no way to make that `CREATE DATABASE` command succeed except to have the locale present, so if that is not possible, you have to run two commands to restore the dump.

Comment: Thanks. By "target OS", do you mean the OS  where the postgresql server is running and the restoring is happening?  If yes, the OS is Lubuntu 18.04. Why does the two-command way works without the locale problem?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant with "target OS". I extended the answer to address your uncertainties.

Comment: Thanks.  
Is it possible modify `CREATE DATABASE` in toc.dat to make `sudo -u postgres pg_restore -C -d postgres dvdrental.tar` work? See my update.

Comment: The table of contents of the dump file cannot be modified.

Comment: Thanks. "Explicitly creating the database works because it uses a locale that exists."  After `CREATE DATABASE dvdrental`, does `sudo -u postgres pg_restore -d dvdrental dvdrental.tar`  read and execute `toc.dat` in the tar dump or not? If `toc.dat` is executed, then there should be the same error when reaching `CREATE DATABASE pagila WITH TEMPLATE = template0 ENCODING = 'UTF8' LC_COLLATE = 'English_United States.1252' LC_CTYPE = 'English_United States.1252'; `. If `toc.dat` is not executed, then the dump will not be loaded at all into the newly created database.

Comment: It does read `toc.dat`, but unless you specify `-C`, it will skip the `CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: Is there a conditional construct around the `CREATE TABLE` command in `toc.dat`, by checking if `-C` is specified? `toc.dat` is binary, how would you check that.

Comment: The conditional construct is in `pg_restore`, just read the code.